# C# Chart to base64 PNG

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xslt, charts

In an MVC Web Application, I need to be able to create a Chart using data in C#, and convert this into a bas64 representation of a PNG, to pass to some XSLT and include in a PDF.

I have tried using:
System.Web.Helpers.Chart - this works, but is limited, and not of great quality. I can't get it to look exactly as I like.

OxyPlot - Seemed a lot more promising, but I am unable to convert to PNG in a Web Application, Export is only possible in WPF or Win Forms.

HighCharts - No way to render to PNG, without using something else like PhantomJS.

Is there a Chart library I can use to achieve this?

Comment: The quality of a MSChart output depends on the size it has. You can make it larger and set the dpi hight to create crisp results.

Comment: _I can't get it to look exactly as I like._ : `System.Web.Helpers.Chart` is difficult to configure because it requires the creation of an awkward XML theme file. Use `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` 
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting?view=netframework-4.8)

You can add this `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization` as a reference in your project. And for converting the chart to base64 image you can just use this.

```
private string GetChartBase64Image(Chart chart)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        chart.SaveImage(memStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] imageArray = memStream.ToArray();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
    }
}
```

In above the example, Class Chart and ChartImageFormat are defined in namespace `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`

Comment: This is in fact what I did 2 years ago! I should have come back and added my own answer. Thank you for taking the time to add this.